# How to prevent re-render while keeping state when using Material UI Autocomplete with multiple options?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using Material UI's `Autocomplete` component with multiple options enabled. I need to be able to select multiple options and update the state every time the value changes. For this, I am using the `onChange` prop. This works fine when using only one option. But with multiple options enabled, every time I select an option, the component re-renders and I am unable to select a second option.

**This is the `onChange` handler:**

```
const handleUserAssignEvent = (event, value) => {
   setSelectedUsers(value)
}
```

**This is the `Autocomplete` component:**

```
const renderUserAssignmentForm = () => {
 const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />
 const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />
 return (
         <Autocomplete
            multiple
            id="usersList"
            options={filteredUsers ?? users ?? []}
            noOptionsText="No users found..."
            disableCloseOnSelect
            onChange={(event, value) => handleUserAssignEvent(event, value)}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.fullname}
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
              <>
                <Checkbox
                  icon={icon}
                  checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                  style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                  checked={selected}
                />
                {option.fullname}
              </>
            )}
            style={{ width: 500 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="outlined"
                label="Users"
                placeholder="User lookup..."
              />
            )}
          />
)}
```

What can I do to be able to update the state without having the Autocomplete component re-render on every change and be able to select multiple options?

Answer (score 1):

I've replicated your example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-example-4m1vd) and there was no problem with selecting multiple options.

Your problem might be that the options prop `filteredUsers` and `users` are related/change with `selectedUsers`.
Or the whole component which contains `renderUserAssignmentForm` being unmounted and mounted again.

Comment: Ok. I'm guessing it must be something else that is causing the parent component to unmount and mount because the `setSelectedUsers` function that modifies the `selectedUsers` state only affects that particular state. Nothing else. As soon as I remove it from the event handler, it works.